# WaitDialogForm.ShowDialog() not processing other code

Tags: c#, devexpress

Pretty new to DevExpress, my company is stuck using 9.3

I've got this very small snippet of code:

```
        wait = new DevExpress.Utils.WaitDialogForm("Please wait...", "Performing SVN check");
        wait.Visible = false;

        wait.ShowDialog();
        ParseSVNResults(CheckSVN());
        wait.Close();
```

My WaitDialog displays, but the code never continues. I put a breakpoint on ParseSVNResults and when I run the code it gets to that line.

It works properly if I just call Show() instead of ShowDialog(), but that gives poor behavior should the user click outside of the Wait form. The application "whites out" like it's stopped responding and the mouse changes into that little rotating circle icon. Also the hour glass that the dialog form shows doesn't rotate. Stupid minor detail, but it looks like the whole application crashed to end users.

Comment: This is what we call [Synchronization By Modal](http://thedailywtf.com/Articles/Synchronization-by-Modal.aspx), also known as `Modal-Enabled Synchronization Semaphore`, or **MESS**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ShowDialog`, by design, "blocks" the code until you close the dialog.  That is the entire purpose.

The reason that `Show()` is causing everything to white out is that your work is happening in the UI thread.  The proper way to handle this would be to move your work (`ParseSVNResults`) into a background thread, via something like `BackgroundWorker` or a `Task`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it the BackgroudnWorker class.

.NET 3.5 so Tasks aren't an option.